# Python Dash - Datatable interactivity and pie chart

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I’m currently trying to create a call back between a data table ('datatable_id') and a pie chart. Essentially, in the data table I can filter rows and select them to appear in a pie chart. The data consists of 4 columns - date, description, hours and price - and is itemised. Thus, I group the data on the basis of the selected rows at the end.

The pie chart should then update itself on the filtered rows and summarise them. The pie chart is not appearing on my dashboard. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd    
import plotly           
import plotly.express as px

import dash            
from dash import dash_table
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#---------------------------------------------------------------

df = pd.read_pickle(r'x')

df = df.reset_index()


#---------------------------------------------------------------
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='datatable_id',
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
            columns=[
                {"name": i, "id": i, "deletable": False, "selectable": False} for i in df.columns
            ],
            editable=False,
            filter_action="native",
            sort_action="native",
            sort_mode="multi",
            row_selectable="multi",
            row_deletable=False,
            selected_rows=[],
            page_action="native",
            export_format = 'xlsx',
            export_headers = 'display',
            page_current= 0,
            page_size= 6,
            style_cell_conditional=[
                {'if': {'column_id': 'Date'},
                 'width': '30%', 'textAlign': 'left'},
                {'if': {'column_id': 'Amount'},
                 'width': '30%', 'textAlign': 'left'},
                {'if': {'column_id': 'Hours'},
                 'width': '30%', 'textAlign': 'left'},
                {'if': {'column_id': 'Description'},
                 'width': '80%', 'textAlign': 'left'},
                {'if': {'column_id': 'Name'},
                 'width': '10%', 'textAlign': 'left'},
            ],
        ),
    ],className='row'),

    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(id='piedropdown',
                options=[
                         {'label': 'Amount', 'value': 'Amount'},
                         {'label': 'Hours', 'value': 'Hours'}
                ],
                value='Amount',
                multi=False,
                clearable=False
            ),
            ],className='six columns'),

    ],className='row'),

    html.Div([

        html.Div([
            dcc.Graph(id='piechart'),
        ],className='six columns'),

    ],className='row'),


])

#------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.callback(
    [Output('piechart', 'figure')],
    [Input('datatable_id', 'selected_rows'),
     Input('piedropdown', 'value')]
)


def update_data(selected_rows,piedropval):
    if len(selected_rows)==0:
        df_filter = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)[['Amount','Hours']].sum()
    else:   
        
        df_filter = df[df.index.isin(selected_rows)]
        
        df_filter = df_filter.groupby('Name', as_index=False)[['Amount','Hours']].sum()
        
    pie_chart=px.pie(
            data_frame=df_filter,
            names='Name',
            values=piedropval,
            hole=.3
            )


    return (pie_chart)

#------------------------------------------------------------------

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```